# Unable to return val_accuracy, Only receiving acc for validation data with generator

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have a model that is training itself with a generator to generate data for a keras model. My Val Accuracy is also named 'acc' and I am not sure how to change this. Here is the code

```
cc_model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(), optimizer=optimizer, 
                 metrics=[metrics.MeanSquaredError(), tf.keras.metrics.Recall(), tf.keras.metrics.Precision(),
                 tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy(name='acc'),
                 CategoricalTruePositives(nb_classes, batch_size)])

trained_history = cc_model.fit(x=training_gen, y=None, batch_size=2, epochs=no_epochs, verbose=1, callbacks=[csv_logger],
                               validation_split=0.0, validation_data=validation_gen, shuffle=True, class_weight=None,
                               sample_weight=None, initial_epoch=0, steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch_travelled, validation_steps=5, 
                               validation_batch_size=2, validation_freq=2, max_queue_size=10, workers=1, use_multiprocessing=False)
```

This is my result

```
Epoch 9/10
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 4.2908 - mean_squared_error: 0.0388 - recall: 0.0000e+00 - precision: 0.0000e+00 - acc: 0.0000e+00 - catego
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 4.2908 - mean_squared_error: 0.0388 - recall: 0.0000e+00 - precision: 0.0000e+00 - acc: 0.0000e+00 - categorical_true_positives: 0.0000e+00
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your

```
validation_steps=None
```

to

```
validation_steps=len(val_gen)
```

where val_gen is your generator for validation. Or u can set to a specific number of steps you'd like.

Comment: Edited to remove division by batch_size